# Page Not Loading properly after redirect

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, browser

I am workign on a codeigniter project and there is this problem:

i have a function to display a list of users in table say

`public function dispaly_users()` this is working fine and the results are displayed as in screenshot.

[image: Page loads normally first]

Now when i click on the approve button i call another function which hits an API. This takes about 2-3 seconds and after that i redirect the page to same function `dispaly_users()` this time the page does not load fully. Here is a screenshot of what haapens :

[image: After the redirect the page does not load properly]

This is happening when is set a flashdata to display any message on the next page if i remove the flashdata the page loads just fine.

The issue show in screenshot happens in Mozilla. In chrome the browser Hangs. 
I want to know what can be the issue with this ? Please help.

Comment: By the looks of it, the page just stops loading, so I would guess there's a PHP error in there somewhere. View the page source, and see what it shows.

Comment: does your site runs all requests through ajax?

Comment: @Criag - No there is no php error there. This is happening when i set a flashdata to show update notificcation from the API Response. If I remove `$this->session->set_flashdata()` then the page is loading fine.

Comment: @itachi - No there is no ajax hit here.

Comment: Is your error reporting turned on?

Comment: @Justinas -  Yes it is

Comment: Show `$this->session->set_flashdata()` code

Comment: `$this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg',"Seller Reqest approved Successfully !!!");`

Comment: is it possibe because of some kind of memory limitaion ??

Answer (score -1):

Go through and check your SQL queries, try adding more if statements after things so that if something goes wrong the if statement will catch it an tell you the error. An other method would be to turn error reporting on like this `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`